# How to divide the Nested List by int 2

Tags: list, nested, average

d=[[5,3,2],[5,1,9],[6,8,3]]

I need to divide this nested list by '2'

Code which I tried.

m=[]

jj=2
`for k,v in zip(d,jj):`

`m.append([k2/v2 for k2,v2 in zip(k,v)])`

`print(m)`

So the output could be like below

```
d=[[2.5,1.5,1],[2.5,0.5,4.5],[3,4,1.5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d=[[5,3,2],[5,1,9],[6,8,3]]
result = [[j/2 for j in i] for i in d]
print(result)
```